# How to create JSArray in DotNetBrowser?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

It seems we can create `JSObject` by `CreateObject` method from a context object, but it seems we cannot create a `JSArray`? Is there a way other than `ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("[]")`?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript array can be created only using the 'ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue' method.

Comment: Is it by design?